# Redirect permanent tag in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, tags

Due to a recent data update to Joomla 3.3.6 there are several URLs that give 404 as the Taxomy component used in Joomla 1.5.26 is not supported in Joomla 3.x 
I want to do a permanent redirect those old URLs to new, I used this rule in the htaccess but does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.vistaalmar.es/tag/(.*)$ http://www.vistaalmar.es/component/taxonomy/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I could give any other ideas for this redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If your links already have `/component/taxonomy/` part and you want to redirect them to `/tag/` you have to change your rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^component/taxonomy/(.*)$ /tag/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps